# Is it possible to apply an external stylesheet to a QT designer UI file?

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'd like to load CSS from a text file and apply it to a QT designer `.ui` file. It appears to me this isn't possible, but I want to make sure.

Here's what I want to do:

```
  auto MainPage = new QWidget(this);
  MainPage->setStyleSheet(cssLoadedFromTextFile); // I want to load my own CSS before setting up the QT Designer widget, and have that CSS be applied to that widget
  m_ui = new Ui::MainPage; // CSS class auto-generated from QT Designer .ui file
  m_ui->setupUi(MainPage);
```

Inside the C++ file compiled from the UI file, `setStyleSheet` gets called again, overwriting the css I'd written. Note that the empty string. This happens even if there's no CSS added to the .ui file in Qt Designer.

```
// inside m_ui->setupUi, in auto-generated class
MainPage->setStyleSheet(QString()) // a stylesheet is applied to MY C++ widget
```

If I comment this out, I see `cssLoadedFromTextFile`, my sub-widget (.ui file created in QT designer) looks good -- cssLoadedFromTextFile is applied, but that's not viable in an auto-generated file.

Is there a way to avoid having this empty stylesheet added inside the auto-generated c++ file? Or is there some other way to apply an external stylesheet to a widget defined in QT designer, so I can share styles between these widgets, and those created with manually-written C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either:

- Set the stylesheet for your whole application at once in the `QApplication` constructor (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#QApplication)). The correct way to do it is pass it as a parameter to your executable command.
  As you may have guessed, doing so applies to all the widget you create, **unless you overwrite their stylesheets**.
- Set the stylesheet for your widget the exact way you do right now, but **after** calling `setupUi`.
  I do not know why you say you want to do it before calling `setupUi`: properties from stylesheets are evaluated reading it from widget itself first, then from its parent, grandparent and so on and last reading it from the application.
  There is not risk of overwriting a stylesheet set on a subwidget of `MainPage` simply by calling:

  ```
   MainPage->setStyleSheet(...)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to apply the styles in `cssLoadedFromTextFile` to `m_ui` (a .ui file created in QT designer). I've tried setting the style sheet after calling `setupUI`. In that case,   `cssLoadedFromTextFile` is not applied to `m_ui`. My assumption is that styles need to be applied to a parent before a child is added in order for the parent's styles to be applied.

Comment: Have you tried to test if your assumption is correct? Because it is definitely incorrect that styles must be applied to parent widgets, then to children. It only takes 6 lines of code to confirm...

Comment: Hey... it worked! I was only able to get the external style to be applied to my subwidget by completely removing all embedded styles in the .ui file. Looks like the auto-generated call to `MainPage->setStyleSheet` must have an empty string as an argument. Adding an style unrelated to the one I'm trying to apply, or adding an invalid stylesheet seems to prevent the external style from being applied. But as you said, calling `setStyleSheet` *after* setting up my subwidget seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help!